# Is it possible to monitor 2 different infrastructures ? - Elastic Cloud

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elastic-cloud

I'm currently using a the trial of Elastic Cloud for my project.

I would like to be able to monitor 2 infrastructures at the same time, I have created a space for each infrastructure as well as 2 agent policies linked to the agents of their own infrastructure.

I was wondering if there was a way to separate the agents by agent policy, for example with a filter, to get only the agents belonging to the space of the chosen infrastructure or by another way.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: by "space" you mean Kibana space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible to create [filtered aliases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-add-alias.html) and then in each Kibana space you can create an index pattern over each alias to only show the data relevant to the underlying agent in the relevant space.

Comment: Sorry but i'm trying to understand. I've to create an alias of an index patern to create an index pattern to only show the data for a specific agent ? Sorry i'm learning. Do you have an exemple for me please ?

Comment: Can you explain which kind of monitoring data you'll be sending to the cluster?

Comment: I'm sending metrics and logs from an Azure Infrastructure

Comment: Using Metricbeat and Filebeat?

Comment: Yes with Elastic Agents and i get some informations with a "custom" filebeat

Comment: Does each agent send the data in their own index or they all send the data in the same index?

Comment: Each agent are sending the data to the same index because it's like that by default.

Comment: I think I just understood your explanation, I tried to make an alias of my metric-* index with a filter to retrieve in my alias only the documents linked to a single machine. And it works. But the problem is that I would like to do this for a whole agent policy, there is no way ?

Comment: You can apply filters on any searchable field that you can find in your documents, I'm not sure the agent policy is saved in a field though

Comment: I see... Thank you so much for your help, you just gave me a huge help for my final thesis. Can I put you in the acknowledgements ?